# prove/disprove that if $|A \mathbin\Delta B| = \aleph$ and $|A \cap B| = \aleph$ then $|A \cup B| = \aleph$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I encountered this question at one of my books that I read about logic and set theory and I can't figure how to do it, I hope someone could help me out here:

if $|A \mathbin\Delta B| = \aleph$ and $|A \cap B| = \aleph$ then $|A \cup B| = \aleph$

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you know the fact that $\kappa +\kappa = \kappa$ for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$ ?

Comment: Can you write $A\cup B$ in terms of $A\Delta B$ and $A\cap B$?

Comment: Note that $A\cup B$ is the disjoint union of $A\mathrel{\triangle}B$ and $A\cap B$.

Comment: What does $\aleph$ without a subscript mean? Does it stand for some particular cardinal, or is it a variable ranging over infinite cardinals?

Comment: @bof it means $\aleph_1$ but in my book it just written as $\aleph$

Comment: @LiziPizi And how is $\aleph_1$ defined in your book? (By the way, what book are you using?)

Comment: @LiziPizi I've seen $\aleph$ used to denote $|\mathbb R|,$ the cardinality of the real line. I can't recall that I've ever seen it used to denote $\aleph_1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\aleph$ would mean $\aleph_0$: The points in contained by exactly one of $A$ or $B$ are countable, that is there exists a sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ listing them. Also the points contained by the both set are countable, similarly, it means, they can be listed in the sequence $b_1, b_2, \ldots$. 
The only thing you have to prove, that the points contained at least on of the sets $A$ and $B$ are listed in a sequence, and to show it, you can use the sequence $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \ldots$ .

If $\aleph$ means the cardinality of real numbers: there is a bijection, that $A \bigtriangleup B$ maps onto $[-2,-1]\cup[1,2]$, and an other, that maps $A \cap B$ onto $(-1,1)$, so you can construct a bijection mappping $A \cup B$ onto $[-2,2]$.

If $\aleph$ means an infinite cardinality, the others cited the statement to use. If $\aleph$ means a finite cardinality, the statement isn't true.

Comment: The OP wrote $\aleph$ not $\aleph_0.$ It's not clear to me whether $\aleph$ means the cardinal of the continuum or a general infinite cardinal.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. I should correct it.